# I'm getting "Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()" running php code to connect to MS SQL in OS X

Tags: php, sql-server, macos

First let me list the specifics: Yosemite 10.10.5 / Xcode 7.0 + tools / PHP 5.5.27

I've installed both FreeTDS and UnixODBC. I believe all my ini files are configured correctly along with my FreeTDS odbc drivers since the **"*tsql*"** command runs fine without errors along with being able to successfully connect to the MS SQL Server with the "***isql***" command (but only as a root user). Nonethelass it connects fine and I can run queries against the database.

My problem is that when I run a PHP script to try to connect to the SQL database I get the following error: 
     "*Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()*"

I have researched multiple links that try to explain how to rectify the situation and unfortunately I am still nowhere near a solution.

http://www.screensugar.co.uk/2010/12/php-with-mssql-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/
http://lkrms.org/php-with-freetds-on-os-x-mavericks/
and a few other similar links.

There are also many links with solutions unfortunately they are for Windows OS and not specifically for OS X.

It seems that these links point to the fact that I don't have PHP configured for MSSQL support. I did a phpinfo() it looks like I don't have my PHP configured to support "**mssql**", no such section found.

Here's where I hope I'm not deviateing from my original question. I still need to see why I'm getting this error. I have a feeling it's because my PHP is not configured for it. Here's my biggest problem. When I try to follow the instructions from the links I cannot run "**phpsize**". I get "No such file or Directory" even though I can clearly see the file in my /usr/bin/ folder.

I would hope to hear from the Stackoverflow community to see if there is anyone who has solved a similar problem or who might have suggestions on where I may look next.

I hope I provided all the necessary information to understand my current situation.

Thank You in Advance!

Comment: Have you tried connecting via PDO?

Comment: I will  try connecting via PDO.  The other questions seem to involve DLL's and WIndows OS. Again I am running OS X. Therefore I cannot duplicate the solution to the previous asked like questions. I will continue to do research to see what solutions are closer to my environment.